# SQLDataSourceParameter parameter for query not working when hard coding a string does

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down menu. My goal is to make it where the currently logged in person is first on the list, followed by an alphabetical list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="userNameDropDown" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
    DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="PK_User" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ApplicationServices %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [PK_User], [Name] FROM [User] ORDER BY CASE WHEN [LoginName] = '@userLoggedIn' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, [Name]">
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="userLoggedIn" Type="String" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is my C# that should set the parameter:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["userLoggedIn"].DefaultValue = User.Identity.Name;
}
```

The result is that the list is shown in alphabetical order, ignoring the logged in person. If I change the SelectCommand and make it hardcoded it works fine:

```
SelectCommand="SELECT [PK_User], [Name] FROM [User] ORDER BY CASE WHEN [LoginName] = 'tunnelld' THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, [Name]
```

In this case it does exactly what I want.

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(User.Identity.Name);
```

results in the output of : tunnelld

Comment: Does wrapping your Page_Load code in a `if(!IsPostBack)` conditional make any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the problem:

```
[LoginName] = '@userLoggedIn'
```

should not have quotes, the following fixes it:

```
[LoginName] = @userLoggedIn
```